# If Filename place to dir dont work

Tags: c#, filenames, if-statement

I have problem with small thing...i coding auto updater and when i downloading .exe file i want to place it to main dir..and others .extension to sub dir.

File.exe = Here is i download place to main dir
Else = place to sub dir...but it isnt working, place all to main dir

```
if(ex[1] == "File.exe")
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        if(File.Exists(String.Format("{0}WoW.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString())))
        {
            File.Copy(String.Format("{0}WoW.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()), String.Format("{0}WoW_zaloha_Awrodar_old_file.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()), false);
            File.Delete(String.Format("{0}WoW.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()));
        }
        else if(File.Exists(String.Format("{0}Wow.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString())))
        {
            File.Copy(String.Format("{0}Wow.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()), String.Format("{0}Wow_zaloha_Awrodar_old_file.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()), false);
            File.Delete(String.Format("{0}Wow.exe", wow.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString()));
        }

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(fs);

        fs.Close();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(byte b in retVal)
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", b));

        if(ex[2] == sb.ToString())
            proceed = false;
    }
}
else
{
    if(File.Exists(MPQpath))
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(MPQpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(fs);

        fs.Close();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(byte b in retVal)
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", b));

        if(ex[2] == sb.ToString())
            proceed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "isn't working"?  That really doesn't tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.Combine` for path manipulation to ensure correctness of filenames. Other than that I don't know what is wrong with your code. Have you traced it though to find out which line is causing your problem.